# Http Response doesn't contain Content-Encoding : giz,deflate

Tags: java, rest

I m using HttpClientBuilder 4.3 jar for auto compression and decompression of data. When I'm sending Http request to Api, in request Accept-Encoding is set automatically to Gzip,Deflate by HttpClientBuilder but the response header which I m getting back from server doesn't have Content-Encoding: Gzip,deflate.

Content-length remains the same with and w/o using HttpClientBuilder.

Not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the gzip or deflate has been set in server side ?

Comment: Yes I have checked the request header, it has Accept-Encoding=Gzip,Deflate.

Comment: Yes, because that's what you put in the request. But it doesn't mean the server is compressing on its side. If there is no `Content-Encoding` header in the response (with `gzip` as a value for example), maybe the server is not set to compress content.

Comment: Ok. I m sending request to Rails application for the json  data so do I need to do some changes even in it. But my request header has Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate. Thanks for the reply 

Comment: Are you building the server AND the client, or only the client ?

Comment: I have an application, where front end is written in Java it connects to Rails app for CRUD through HttpClientBuilder 4.3 jar for HTTP request. I have added the deflate support in the Rails application. Now my response header has Vary Accept-Encoding, Origin header. I m not sure whether it is supporting the compression or not after the changes in Rails app, because still doesn't have Content-Encoding as deflate in response and even content-length is missing. Thanks !!!